# Agregar un Nuevo Fragmento y enlazarlo con el menu Drawer (Android)

Tags: java, xml

Estoy  intentado editar  una Aplicación  android, de momento funciona muy bien, pero me he visto  en la necesidad  de Ampliar sus funciones.

Lo que deseo es agregar un nuevo  fragmento a la aplicación.
La aplicación  ya tiene su Drewer definido asi: 
[image: Drawer de la App]

Necesito agregar  1 mas , podria ser un "hello Word" lo que deseo es agregar una opción  mas de las que  ya tiene.

Otra Duda es que no se como añadir
Un nuevo Atributo al Archivo  R.java para crear el R.id y enlazarlo.
¿Alguna manera de hacerlo desde Android  estudio?
Ya probre agregarlo de muchas  maneras  pero la aplicación  se cierra al colocar el nuevo Fragmento ,   Necesito  de su Ayuda.

Actualización

Realize el proceso  que me recomendó, en efecto el R.java creo el Nuevo  atributo  R.id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno puedes ver el nuevo id esta siendo utilizado  pero al parecer al crear el nuevo Fragmento  y enlazarlo  con el id de layout la aplicación  da error y se cierra, el fragmento lo creo desde aqui.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

Se crea un nuevo archivo  fragment_blank.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/img_no"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Y el archivo  BlankFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.anylabs.new.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}  '

Pero al preciosar  el botton en la aplicacion esta se cierra, que estare asiendo mal?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solución:

La Class Fragment estaba Incompleta, y eso daba  el error pero el Rebuild soluciono todo , gracias  por ayudarme hasta la próxima

Comment: Me refiero a que coloques el código que tengas, que aquí no te lo harán por tí, además sería una base para el que te pueda ayudar no tenga que empezar desde 0.

Comment: Todo el código funciona, solo necesitó  alguien  que este familiarizado  con android Studio y me diga que el procedimiento  para agregarlo  adecuadamente  , como sabes en el Ide casi todo es automático  solo necesito saber lo que dice  la pregunta

Comment: Pero si deseas ver parte del codigo , pues dime y lo coloco, deseas  ver el código  del fragmento  o el archivo  layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar información de como construyes el layout porque podrias estar usando items personalizados, si no es este el caso, simplemente agrega un item al grupo:

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icono1"
        android:title="Item1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Item2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icono2"
        android:title="Item2"
        />
</group>
```

Comment: Hola Amigo muchas  gracias  por responder,  de hecho es correcto los  items estan en un grupo. Y ya agrege manualmente  el items que deseo y al ejecutar la app aparece, pero como un botton que no enlaza a nada ya que Id+@ esta vacío  en el archivo  R.java y MainActivity.java por eso necesito encontrar una forma de agregarlo de modo  que me genere  el id/itemsnuevo y poder utilizar en mi drawer :)  creo que es items perzonalizado ya que la app es una plantilla pre-frabricada pero con el codigo fuente completo

Comment: Si no agrega un id respectivo dentro del archivo R.java simplemente realiza un "Rebuild" del proyecto. Dime que resultado tienes.

Comment: Excelente  , lo probare y posteriormente  comentaré  el resultado.

Comment: Amigo, actualize la pregunta, @Elenasys